# HTML won't load linked CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn HTML and have been following a tutorial online.(https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) the tutorial does have some misinformation, so I've been looking on here for help as well. I have reached the point where you use external CSS files rather than using the `<style>` function.
My code is in /HTML/[ProjectName]/project.html, while my CSS is in /HTML/[ProjectName]/CSS/styles.css. Below are both files;

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

p1 {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Linked CSS </title>

<head>
  <link rel="style" type="text/css" href="/CSS/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1> The CSS is in a separate doc </h1>
  <p1> Let's see how this works out </p1>
  <a href="/CSS/Styles.css" target="_blank">
    <p2> Link to CSS file </p2>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

From what I've read the css is properly linked to my file, and when I open the link it opens to the css page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your question you say that the _"CSS is in /HTML/[ProjectName]/CSS/style.css"_ but the link in your html is _"/CSS/styles.css"_. Is your CSS `style.css` or `styles.css`? Also, `rel="style"` is incorrect and should be `rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: Try this with stylesheet `<link rel = "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href = "CSS/styles.css">`

Comment: Thanks for the help, my problem was solved!

Comment: @Atat Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\styles.css">`and check the spelling of your CSS file because they are different in question and in your code.

Comment: Please stop re-editing your question to include unnecessary text

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update your code to match your correct filename.

If your CSS is stored in the `/HTML/[ProjectName]/CSS/style.css`, then you should it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

It`s easy. Take it

```
link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='CSS/style.css'
```

and read [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)